# Compute $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^n}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Compute $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^n}dz$$

Im thinking of using cauchy's integral formula since it satisfies the properties.

So we just have $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^n}dz=\frac{2i\pi}{(n-1)!}e^0=\frac{2i\pi}{(n-1)!}$$

This is the first time i'm doing this so i'm not sure if i did it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally have gone with the [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), because I find that easier. Assuming $n \geq 1$, the residue (i.e. the coefficient of $\frac1z$ in the Laurent series) of $\frac{e^z}{z^n}$ at the single pole $z = 0$ is $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$. Thus the integral in a counterclockwise direction around that pole is equal to $2\pi i\frac1{(n-1)!}$.

Comment: Interesting. But i just noticed something, apparently my answer was supposed to be $\frac{2i\pi}{(n-1)!}$ would that be alligned with yours as well?

Comment: @Danxe Yes, it does. I had the $(n-1)!$ in the first fraction, it just disappeared in the final result. The integral is always equal to $2\pi i$ times the residue (although if your curve encloses several poles, then you have to add the residues from each pole).

Comment: Ahh thank you. Yeah i get your answer. thanks for helping.